# Can an Apple expert reset or delete my firmware password on 2017 iMac running Monterey remotely or must I go to Genius Bar at store? I have receipt

Tags: imac, apple-store, firmware-password

I can't get to an Apple store. Is there another way to do this. I have my receipt on line for proof of purchase.

Comment: And you wouldn't call Apple because... reasons?  Pick up the phone.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Apple SE! If you'd shorten your title to a briefer description of the problem and lengthen your question with details on what you've tried, specifications, and what you would like an answer about, that would be great and help people to answer your questions in a timely and helpful manner.

Comment: I had a shorter title but my question was closed, said someone else had same question, but it was too basic and answer was n/a…I had serious spinal surgery and haven’t been cleared for driving yet so I thought Apple could do this remotely. I want to thank y’all for your help, much appreciated. I’ve got what I need. This site is awesome. I still have my first Apple SE 30 from the 80s!!

Answer (score 1):

For sure open a remote support case with Apple. They will review the details and let you know if they can accommodate your request remotely.

I have never had to do this, but my understanding is that you can start the process over the phone with Apple Support, so long as you have proof of ownership.

From [Mr.Macintosh](https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-remove-mac-firmware-password-new-way-if-you-have-a-2018-2020-t2-mac/):

"How to remove the firmware password with Apple Support.

If you have proof of ownership, Apple can remove the firmware password and retain your data for Mac Devices from 2011-2020. They will walk you through a process (Shift-Control-Option-Command-S) that will show you a code that you can give the Apple support agent. The agent will use that code to send you a file so you can create a USB boot disk that will remove the firmware password."

Do read the whole article.

For a detailed description of how this works [Apple EFI firmware passwords and the SCBO myth](https://reverse.put.as/2016/06/25/apple-efi-firmware-passwords-and-the-scbo-myth/).

For more recent Macs with the T2 chip, you can do it without Apple Support assistance. Again, read the Mr.Macintosh article.

Comment: Thanks for the technical link.  Fantastic reading!

Comment: It's worth noting that in Apple's view, "proof of ownership" means the original proof of purchase issued when the Mac was first sold by Apple or by an Apple store or by an Apple-approved dealer.